# Why doesn't ASP.NET MVC have live reload? Is there any issue with the CLR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am curious why in 2017 we still have to compile and run our ASP.NET MVC applications after every c# change.

Why can't we just make a change, hit refresh in the browser and have our code behind the scenes reload by itself?

What is the underlying technical reason preventing this?

Comment: Not sure this is the best place to ask this, but yeah - I generally dislike working with eclipse/java, but the ability to edit code and have it take effect immediately (as in, yes, immediately, without having to anything at all) is pretty awesome, and to have the same thing in ASP.NET would be a killer feature.

Comment: The rosyln compiler in .net core has this feature.

Comment: BTW I made that comment on the basis of having issues with Edit and Continue in ASP.NET in older versions of Visual Studio. I did a bit of experimenting with the latest version and it works almost as well as Eclipse hot-swapping, except you have to hit a breakpoint first, then resume when you've finished editing.

Comment: Actually I take that back, Edit and Continue even with VS 2017 is still very patchy - more than half the edits I make don't allow it. Eclipse hot-swapping is much more flexible - it's actually very rarely I need to terminate and restart.